# Rman Backup command

Tags: oracle

Backpup database command in rman oracle 11g  will backup in which format 
1  it must backup as backup set 
2. it can backup as backup set
3.it must backup as image copy 
4. it can backup as image copy

Answer (score -1):

Point 2 and 4 are correct.

Image copies are exact byte-for-byte copies of files. You can create an image copy by copying a file at the operating system level. Unlike copying files at the operating system level, however, image copies created through RMAN are recorded in the RMAN repository so that RMAN can use these copies during database restore operations and recovery.

Backup sets are logical entities produced by the RMAN BACKUP command. This command can produce one or more backup sets on disk or tape devices. Although image copies cannot use all RMAN features, their advantages are that you can apply incremental backups to them (synthetic full backups) and you can use them directly in place without first copying them, for very fast restores.